# To check the repeating digits in a single number in JS

Tags: javascript

I used `random function`, to generate a 4 digit number.

The generated `4 digit random number` should not be in the sequence of 1111, 2222, 3333, .... The generated random number could be of  **any number**  except 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444,..

I used the below approach,

But, i could get the repeating of digits using the below code. Could somebody please help.

```
function repeatingDigit(n) {
    let num = n.toString();
    for (var i = 0; i <= num.length; i++) {
       if (num.substr(i) == num.substr(++i)) {
            alert('This pattern can not be used');
        }
       else {
            return parseInt(n);
       }
     }
}
repeatingDigit(Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just check if it's divisible by `1111`:

```
function repeatingDigit(n) {
    if (n % 1111 === 0) {
       alert('This pattern can not be used');
    }

    return n;
 }

repeatingDigit(Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to test for that:

```
function repeatingDigit(n) {
    let num = n.toString();
    if (/(\d)\1{3}/.test(num)) {
        alert('This pattern can not be used');
    } else {
        return parseInt(n);
    }
}
repeatingDigit(Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000));
```

The regular expression `/(\d)\1{3}/` tests for digits `\d` and checks if the following three characters are the same as the first found digit.

Comment: regex can be something like /\b(\d)\1+\b/ too

Comment: @SarveshChitko If you are sure, that n will always be 4 digit numbers. Because your pattern matches any repeating digit from 2 repetitions to infinite repetitions, e.g. `22`, `333`, `4444`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use every() function which is inbuilt function provided by javascript to check wheather number is repeated or not after splitting number to array.

```
function repeatingDigit(num) {
var arr = String(num).split('');
if(arr.every(function (digit) { return digit === arr[0]}))
    return 'Repeated Number!!';
else 
    return num; 
}

console.log(repeatingDigit(Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000)))
```

Hope This Answer Will Help You! Happy Coding :)

Comment: @ Sumit, how does arr.every returns digit === arr[0] ? I couldn't get that.

Comment: Yah, basically I just converted whole number to array format separated by comma just like for example number is (1234) I converted it into (1,2,3,4) and then after I used every function() which will be used to itterate an array and give us to current element from array which is our digit. After that I just compared all the digits with digit which is located at 0'th position in array. so if our number from 1'st position to X is === our 0'th position digit then it will give us an message that "Repeated Number" otherwise we will get actual random number. I hope you will get better idea. Thanks:)